Python debugging in VSC: Cannot see Call Stack during time.sleep()
I am debugging python in MS Visual Studio Code and stepping through the code with F11.
When I get to a timer sleep() method, during the "sleep period" the Call Stack goes blank and I have no way of knowing on what line of code the debugger is waiting.
def someMethod():

    time.sleep(30)
    print("Finished Timer, still in method")

def main():

    someMethod()
    print("Finished Timer, back in main()")

# Python script starts here
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

If I had a long sleep timer and walked away for my desk or maybe someone else arrived how would they know on what line of code the debugger is located while it is waiting for the sleep() to finish?

You will have to wait 30 second to see
Finished Timer, still in method
Finished Timer, back in main()


Why? And is there no other way of knowing what line of code is currently executing?

What is your Platform?

MS VSC 1.91.1 running on OS Linux x64 6.1.100-1-Manjaro. For the python interpreter I am using Python 3.12.4 ('.venv': venv) ./venv/bin/python For the debugger I debug the Currently active Python file in VSC using MS Python Debugger Extension v2024.10.0
